# How do I use parameter in an MDX query?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssas, mdx

I am using parameter called `Region`. It is having 3 values; `Region L1`, `Region L2` and `Region L3`.
I want user to select the region and that should trigger the `MDX` query in `SSAS`. 
Below is the query:

```
    select non empty

    {([Region].[Region L3].children , [Product Line].[Product Line L2].children)} on rows,

   {[Measures].[Clients], [Measures].[Commission]} on columns
  from [Products]
```

So, the report will initially ask to select the region level from the dropdown. If the user selects `Region L2`, the parameter will take the value of `Region L2` and the query would be [Region].**[Region L2]**.children.

I tried `strtoset()` but not sure, how would I use it here.I am not sure if I can do something like `[Region].[@Region].children`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your parameter should be set to a valid unique name in your dimension.

```
="[Region].[Region L2].&[MyRegion]"
```

or

```
="[Region].[Region L1].children"
```

Then in your MDX script use the parameter as follows:

```
select non empty STRTOSET(@Region,CONSTRAINED) on rows,
{[Measures].[Clients], [Measures].[Commission]} on columns
from [Products]
```

So you have to populate your parameter taking in account that its value must be a valid unique name in your parameter.

If you are manually specifying the values in your parameter use:

[image]

Use the expression to produce the valid unique name in `Value`, i.e.:

```
="[Region].[Region L2].Children"
```

Let me know if this helps.